# Problem when running git push Heroku, Ruby version is 2.6.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to push something to Heroku by this command

`git push heroku master`

and it gave me this error :

`Your Ruby version is 2.6.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3
Failed to install gems via Bundler.
Detected a mismatch between your Ruby version installed and
Ruby version specified in Gemfile or Gemfile.lock.`

`You can correct this by running:
$ bundle update --ruby
$ git add Gemfile.lock
$ git commit -m "update ruby version"`

I changed my Gemfile from 2.6.3 to 2.6.4, ofcourse update the gemfile by bundle install command, but I failed. I also tried to run all the command they gave me, but nothing changed, I still have the error. When I check, the Gemfile still 2.6.4, but the error still told me that `your Gemfile specified 2.6.3`.

Could you still give me some ideas for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the content of `.ruby-version` file at the root of your project?

Comment: Also, try updating ruby version in `Gemfile` and then run `bundle install`, then do `git add .` and `git commit -m "message"` -> then `git push heroku master`

Comment: Hey @Anh, you can also try deleting your ```Gemfile.lock``` and run ```bundle install``` again.

Comment: @allenbrkn : do you mean the file `.ruby-version` at the same folder with the file `Gemfile` ? When I check it, it just only gave me this `ruby-2.6.4` so I am very confusing. By the way, I also try to updated by run all your command but nothing change. Do you have any other idea for me?

Comment: @Violeta : when I try to delete my `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again, it borned a new `Gemfile.lock` ofcourse, and when I check this file, it said that ruby version is `2.6.4`.  Could you please give me something new?

Comment: @AnhBui can you check if you're on `master` branch right now. Run `git status` or `git branch -a`(this will highlight current branch).

Comment: Can you show the `ruby` version line in your `Gemfile`? Also Your `.ruby-version` file must have only `2.6.4` and not `ruby-2.6.4`. Ex: https://github.com/brinkirn/authza/blob/master/.ruby-version

Comment: @allenbrkn : here is something in my `.ruby-version` file, https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipNWXlmRYX016eCQnzMgTHJo9qDW_dj4TqrAD8f9 it is `ruby-2.6.4`, not `2.6.4` , so if I change it to `2.6.4` , will it work ?

Comment: @allenbrkn : in my `gemfile`, the `ruby` version line is `ruby 2.6.4p104`, so I think the ruby 's version is 2.6.4, so I think it will work ?

Comment: Yes change the `.ruby-version` file to just `2.6.4` like my file here - https://github.com/brinkirn/authza/blob/master/.ruby-version . Also, in `Gemfile` just add `ruby '2.6.4'` - Like here - https://github.com/brinkirn/authza/blob/master/Gemfile#L4

Comment: If you want to use specific patch level like `p104` then, you'll have to do like this - https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/gemfile.5.html#PATCHLEVEL i.e., in your case, add this to `Gemfile` -> `ruby "2.6.4", :patchlevel => "104"`

Answer (score 0):

I was breaking my head.

$ ruby -v
ruby **2.7.4p191** (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$ bundle *2.2.17* platform --ruby
ruby **2.7.4p191**

$ cat .ruby-version
**2.7.4p191**

$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep -A 2 RUBY
RUBY VERSION
ruby **2.7.4p191**

$ cat Gemfile | grep -A 2 "ruby '2.7.4'"
ruby '2.7.4', :patchlevel => '191'

They all point to the same ruby version: **2.7.4p191**. Reading the Heroku log output, I edited the line in the bin/bundle file where it says

#!/usr/bin/env ruby2.7

to

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

That's all.